# Python: modifying enclosing variable in function

Tags: python, variables

Are there any ways to modify the enclosing variables with functions written outside of the main function?

I want to do this:

```
def modify_a():
    nonlocal a
    a =+ 1

def process_abc(some_criteria):
    a, b, c = generate(some_criteria)
    modify_a()
    return a, b, c

a, b, c = process_abc()
```

I tried the following, but I wonder if there's a way to make the above work. If there's any, is it bad coding practice?

```
def modify_a(a=a):
    a =+ 1

def process_abc(some_criteria):
    a, b, c = generate(some_criteria)
    a = modify_a(a)
    return a, b, c

a, b, c = process_abc()
```

Comment: `a` is in no sense an "enclosing variable" here.  You'd have to actually put the definition of `modify_a` *inside* the definition of `process_abc()` for that to be true.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it is by modifying the parent frame.

Either way, this is a very bad idea. Functions are a form of encapsulation.

If you wish to modify the parent data, you can pass a mutable structure like so:

```
def modify_a(a=a):
    a[0] =+ 1

def process_abc(some_criteria):
    a, b, c = generate(some_criteria)
    a= [a]
    a = modify_a(a)[0]
    return a, b, c

a, b, c = process_abc()
```

It is generally frowned upon though.